# How to rewrite address bar URL from mysite.webhost.com to mysite.com using Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a website 'mysite.com' hosted with 'webhost.com'. When people visit my website, they are redirected from mysite.com to mysite.webhost.com. That is ok, but is there a way to retain the address bar display to 'mysite.com'? My webhost supports Apache mod_rewrite feature.

Comment: Do you have a proper virtual host created in Apache for 'mysite.com'?

Comment: Not sure. My site is on nearlyfreespeech.net and don't have much control on the actual server. What should I be doing, assuming everything on Apache's been done right?